# How do I fix "no such file or directory found" error when trying to run a mounted container?

Tags: ruby, docker, redis, runtime, sinatra

I have been working through the docker book and I am currently working on starting a Redis-enabled Sinatra application. The book tells me to write out this code:

```
docker run -d -p 4567 --net=net --name webapp_redis -v $PWD/webapp_redis:/opt/webapp jamtur01/sinatra
```

However when running it, I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/webapp/bin/webapp\": stat /opt/webapp/bin/webapp: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

I am not sure to fix it as the directory exists within the file that I am in.

Comment: Are you sure that `./webapp_redis/bin/webapp` exists in your working directory?

Comment: Your `-v` bind mount option is overwriting the thing the container is trying to run; if the directory layout doesn't match up exactly you'll get this error.  I'd recommend removing this option to run the code actually built into the image.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help guys! I was able to fix it.. I realized that I used `mkdir -p` when creating the folder so there was another webapp_redis inside my directory. I deleted that and it works now :)